# onmouseover to change Function Name?

Tags: javascript, function, scriptaculous

Is there a way to change the function name in JavaScript when using onmouseover?

In the HTML DOM we have something like this:

`<img class="..." src="..." alt="..." onclick="click1()"> onmouseover="changeFunction()">`

In JavaScript:

`function changeFunction() {....}`

`function onclick1() {...}`

The event that I want to trigger is something like this:

When the mouse is hovered over an Image, this would trigger the 'onmouseover' function which changes the "onclick function name" that would change the name from "function click1() {...}" to " function click2(){...}.

`*hovers over image* and triggers the Name change`

`function click1() is changed to function click2()`

This would still retain the other codes inside of it. All it does is change the name of the function.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Technically, I don't there's anyway to modify the name of existing function, but you can definitely bind the `click` event to a *different* function. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: So instead of having "function click1() {...}", "function click2() {...]," ... " function click100(){..}. Im trying to minimize the amount of coding inside my JS by having just a few lines of code written to change the function name. Of course I could always copy and paste since i already have the onclick to do exactly what i want. I was just wondering if there was a possible way to modify the name.

Comment: You are over complicating it. I've never in my career needed to change a functions name. instead use data attributes which you then use in the function to determine which gallery to display.

Comment: I really don't understand your question. You cannot change the name of function because it is like a definition for your software like a constant (`const`). it is like you try to modify a word in a dictionary like: *Madness*  (mad′nis), n. the state of being mad; insanity. No for me this is *Safe* and you change it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
<script>
  function click1() {
    console.log('click 1');
  }
  function click2() {
    console.log('click 2');
  }
  function changeFunction(element) {
    element.onclick = click2;
  }
</script>

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x65" onclick="click1()" onmouseover="changeFunction(this)">
```

When you mouse over the image, it will change the onclick function from `click1` to `click2`.

Comment: After reading p.s.w.g's comment I'm actually not sure if this is what you want. If it's not, could you clarify your end goal?

Comment: The goal here is to min max the coding i need to do for 100's of images. By changing the function name, i would be to cut down the amount of spaces require to code for each individual name. Of course I already have the onclick function to work, its just a matter of copy and paste and changing the name. The image is an onlick function which open up to a image gallery, and there are 100's of images that have the exact same thing.

Comment: Can you just have them all point to the same click1() function?

Comment: Im assuming if i do this it would require Logical operators which would be slightly more complicated than the code i already have.

Comment: @DisplayNAEM I'm not sure why you'd need any logical operators, and anyway, a few logical operators are definitely less complicated than trying to change the name of a function. Use *parameters* to generalize a function, e.g. `click("img1")` vs `click("img2")` or get the [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) from the event info. Either way, you don't need 100 different functions or the same function with 100 different names.